# not able to call javascript function

Tags: javascript

i want to write div in innerhtml , but i  am not able to write onclick on div.
please help!!

below is the piece of code i wrote:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
var act = "SSC00457";
innerHtml = "<div class='subMenuDiv' id='"+act+"'    onclick='alert(this);callMenu(this);'>"+act+"</div>";
td.innerHTML = innerHtml;


function callMenu(obj)
{
alert('id : '+obj );
}
```

here i am able to see alert before call to callMenu
but i am not able to print alert in callMenu function. please help!!

Comment: try onclick='alert("+td+");callMenu("+td+");'

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
var act = "SSC00457";

var subMenuDiv = document.createElement('div');
subMenuDiv.className = 'subMenuDiv';
subMenuDiv.id = act;
subMenuDiv.innerHTML = act;
td.appendChild(subMenuDiv);

subMenuDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(this);
    callMenu(this);
});

function callMenu(obj){
    alert('id : '+obj );
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GeA9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
document.getElementById(act).addEventListener('click',function(){
alert(this.id)
},false);
```